# How can I sort by a column while binning another

Tags: python, cut, bins

I am trying to cut float values of each country while grouping them by continent.  I had posted this previously but I got a little farther so I am going to put where I am at now.  I wrote the following code:

```
groups =  pd.value_counts(pd.cut(renew['% Renewable'], 5))
groups = pd.DataFrame(groups).reset_index()
```

and I got the following DataFrame:

```
    % Renewable counts
0   (2.213, 15.754]     7
1   (15.754, 29.228]    4
2   (29.228, 42.702]    2
3   (56.176, 69.65]     2
4   (42.702, 56.176]    0
```

Now I would like to merge with the 'Continent' and create a Series with a multindex of 'Continent' and '% Renewable' and the counts as the Eeries value.

I would like to merge these so it is a count in a multindex Series grouped by continents with the counts of each country in each bin.  An example would be like this:

```
Asia      (2.213, 15.754]       3
          (15.754, 29.228]      1
          (29.228, 42.702]      2
          (56.176, 69.65]       0
          (42.702, 56.176]      0
Europe    (2.213, 15.754]       2
          (15.754, 29.228]      2
          (29.228, 42.702]      0
          (56.176, 69.65]       1
          (42.702, 56.176]      0
>>....and so on
```

Here is a piece of the data frame I am getting the info from:

```
    Country Continent   % Renewable
0   China   Asia    (15.754, 29.228]
1   United States   North America   (2.213, 15.754]
2   Japan   Asia    (2.213, 15.754]
3   United Kingdom  Europe  (2.213, 15.754]
4   Russian Federation  Europe  (15.754, 29.228]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say why that particular error happens without seeing the data, but first put all the variables you want to group by in the first argument, e.g.

```
groups = renew.groupby(['Continent', pd.cut(renew['% Renewable'], 5)])
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same thing.  I am going too edit it with a piece of the dataframe to give more context.

Comment: I was also thinking that instead of making the value_counts Series, I might have to write an apply() scross the data frame, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: But then I get the following error >>TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: I think it's best if you just rephrase the question starting with an example of your input and then an example of what the output should look like. As it is, the title and the question are a little confusing. If last frame in your current question is the input, it seems it already has some kind of intervals in it?

Comment: OK I will add a new question and restructure it.